# Ruby ActiveRecord: How to connect two rooms with an exit

Tags: ruby, activerecord, orm, rails-activerecord, adventure

I am making a small text-adventure, and I want to use ActiveRecord as Object Relational Mapping.

What I'm having trouble with, is understanding how to connect two rooms together using an exit.
The following facts are a given:

- A room can have multiple exits
- An exit can be in different directions (it has a 'direction' field). Also, it might have other parameters such as 'locked', etc. that I want to add later.
- An exit connects up two rooms.

However, now I am stuck:

What I have so far

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :exits
    has_many :neighbours, through: :exits
end

class Exit < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :room, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :room_dest, foreign_key: "room_dest_id", class_name: "Room", dependent: :destroy

end
```

but this is incomplete. `room.neighbours`, for example, is not working at all.

What mostly baffles me is how to make exits work two-ways: If I add an exit on one room, it won't be in the `room.exits` list in the other room.

What works is: (given an exit connecting `room1` and `room2`) 
`room1.first.exits.first.room_dest` (this is `room2`)
But `room2.exits` is empty, and `room1.neighbours` shows a list containing only itself.

How is this done properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get room.neighbours working, I believe you would first need to change

```
belongs_to :room_dest, foreign_key: "room_dest_id", class_name: "Room", dependent: :destroy
```

to

```
 belongs_to :neighbour, foreign_key: "room_dest_id", class_name: "Room"
```

Note that I removed the dependent: option because you probably don't want to destroy Rooms when Exits are deleted. You want dependent: :destroy on the has_many relationship with exits.

Now we've really solidified the one-way binding of Exit. But if you think about it, isn't "Exit" just one-way by definition? While this seems limiting at first, you can utilize this to define "entrances" of the Room. That is your connection from the neighbour to the original Room. Something like:

```
has_many :entrances, class_name: "Exit", foreign_key: "room_dest_id"
```

Or you could define a method that queries Exits and checks if either room_id or room_dest_id is the Room ID. In this case I would rename "Exit" class to be something more generic. Unfortunately I can't think of any built-in AR association that would do this multi-key association for you. It wouldn't really work right because things like association.build/create would not know which of the keys to set. But it's a relatively simple method or set of methods that could still return a scope which you could operator on:

```
has_many :connections, dependent: :destroy # For ease of creating connection, not as useful for querying them

def exits
  Connection.where(["room_id = :id OR dest_room_id = :id", id: self.id])
end

def neighbours
  exits.map do |conn|
    conn.room_id == self.id ? conn.dest : conn.source
  end
end
```

You could make the query more complex if you actually want some of the  Connections to be one-way. Or write other methods that build on this since it is not executed immediately. You could still chain .first(), another .where(), etc on it.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is a very good idea to make them directonal; Let the controller figure out which direction we move in, the model doesn't have to care. 
Also, thanks on the `dependent: :destroy` tip. You learn something new every day :-)